# Context incorrect error whicle using bpy.ops.paint.add_simple_uvs()

Tags: python, blender

What is the correct context to run bpy.ops.paint.add_simple_uvs() in blender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context for the painting operators would be the 3D View. When running a script from the text editor or console then 3D view will not be the active area which is then causing the context error.

[This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6105/935) explains more as well as showing examples of how to override the context.